# Keep only last line of a repeated pattern

Tags: c, ubuntu, text, lines

I would like to know if it is possible to delete all the lines of a selected pattern except the last one. It is not so easy to explain, so I will make an example.

I have a text file with content similar to this:

```
A sent (1)
A received (1)
B sent (1)
B sent (2)
B sent (3)
B received (1)
```

I would like to have an alternation between "sent" and "received" messages, where the "sent" one is the last between the sent messages with the same letter. So I need an output like:

```
A sent (1)
A received (1)
B sent (3)
B received (1)
```

Is there some program that can do something like that? I can use either Ubuntu or Windows, or build a simple C/C++ application, if necessary.

Comment: You probably need to write a small program by yourself wither in c, c++, php, pearl or [gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) or some other language of your choice.

Comment: I am assuming that the number in parentheses increment only if the letter and the word preceding it recurred, is that right? if that's the case, then you can just concentrate on the third row, if the number increments, then keep the last line with the greatest number, and erase the lines before it.

Comment: @meriororen Yes, you are right. It is exactly as you said. I probably need to write a C application to delete the lines based if they contain "sent" and the last number is lower with respect to the next line.

Comment: Well, I was going to say it, but apparently it's been answered, you can also take the approach of reading the first two words, and see if they are the same with the previous line, count it, and reprint it with awk. It will be much easier.

Comment: Or you could use the `uniq` command, which is almost purpose-built for this problem. (See my answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
tac FILE | uniq -w 6 | tac
```

We:

1. Reverse-print the file using `tac` (necessary for `uniq` to work right here).
2. Weed out duplicate lines basing uniqueness on only the first 6 characters (thereby ignoring the incrementing number in parantheses). Only the first line of a set of duplicate lines is kept, which is why we have used `tac`.
3. Then reverse-print the file again so it's in the order you want.

Comment: Very easy and fast method! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ha! Didn't know about `tac`, which has a very Unix-ey mnemonic name. Thanks.

Comment: @MOehm, I discovered it accidentally one day. I was thinking, "Now how will I reverse this file?" And then `tac` occurred to me and I thought, "No. There's no way..." And then it worked and my appreciation of Unix grew even more. For reference: the `qinu` command does not make duplicates :-(

Answer (score 1):

Under linux, this can be a one-liner, for example in `awk`:

```
awk '$1 $2 != prev {if (buf) print buf} {prev = $1 $2; buf = $0} END {print buf}' mylog.txt
```

The exact syntax depends on your pattern. Here, I just use the first two words (`$1 $2`) of the line to determine whether a line should be skipped. The skipped lines (`$0`) are stored in a temporary which is printed when the pattern is different or at the `END`.

If it is okay to print the first line of a similar block instead of the last line, the script reduces to:

```
awk '$1 $2 != prev; {prev = $1 $2}' mylog.txt
```

or you can use the even more succinct alternative:

```
uniq -w 6
```

which sorts out unique lines, but considering only the first 6 characters.

Answer (score 0):

In C, something like this will do:

```
bool isFirstSent = false;
bool isSecondSent = false;
char *firstLine = getLine(file); // getline returns a char array 
                                 // if a line exists and NULL otherwise 
if (strstr(firstLine, "sent"))
   isFirstSent = true;
char *secondLine = getLine(file);

while (secondLine)
{
   if (strstr(secondLine, "sent"))
      isSecondSent = true;
   else
      isSecondSent = false;
   if (isFirstSent != isSecondSent)
      printf("%s", firstLine);
   free(firstLine);
   isFirstSent = isSecondSent;
   firstLine = secondLine;
   secondLine = getLine(file);
}

free(firstLine);
```